# `react-select` add new value dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a `react-select` `Async` component. It has `loadOptions` assigned and it works fine when selecting `options` from this list.

For example I happen to have a list:

```
[{value:"111", label:"3 x one"}, {value:"222", label:"3 x two}]
```

I want to be also able to add `options` to this component dynamically, for example I want to add `{value: "333"}`

How can I do it?

Thank you :-)

Comment: I made the following logic -> I added in the list last item "other" and when user selects it, the new field appears below with ability to add a new item inside the list. It's probably not the best way, but works pretty well.

Comment: I do not want user to select it, new items need to be added dynamically by for example clicking on the button outside of the component.

Comment: So what is the problem? Create new component that will add new option in your array.

Comment: My button needs to add new option not to the list of available options but to the list of `already selected` options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `useState` (deprecated)

```js
const Example = () => {
  const [loadOptions, setLoadOptions] = useState([
    { value: '111', label: '3 x one' },
    { value: '222', label: '3 x two' }
  ])

  const handleClick = () => {
    setLoadOptions([...loadOptions, { value: '333', label: '3 x three' }])
  }

  return (
    <>
      <AsyncSelect 
        ...
        loadOptions={loadOptions} 
        ...
      />
      <Button onClick={handleClick}></Button>
    </>
  )
}
```

For selected values, just try to manipulate props `value` and `onChange` manually ([docs](https://react-select.com/props))

**Update** codesandbox link

[image: Edit react-codesandboxer-example]

Comment: `handleClick` is not supposed to add new option to the list of options. It is supposed to add option to `already selected` options.

Comment: @JacekWojcik you should demo your case in more detail, codesandbox maybe

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-q3n2c?file=/example.js

please refer to `handleClick2`

Comment: @JacekWojcik please check my sandbox link in answer

Answer (score 1):

`options` is an array with options that can be selected.
`value` is a value that is selected.
The two are separate. You can have a list of `options` (let say ["a","b"]) while displayed values are different (let say ["c","d"]).
You can update the options in many ways. You might also want to control the options on your own "externally" without using defaultOptions+loadOptions (which is a bit messy in v2 by the way as the defaultOptions are loaded only on init and not updated later on).

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

function Example() {
  const [loadOptions] = useState([
    { value: "111", label: "3 x one" },
    { value: "222", label: "3 x two" }
  ]);

  const [optionSelectedList, setOptionSelectedList] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOptionSelectedList([
      ...optionSelectedList,
      { value: "333", label: "3 x three" }
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        options={loadOptions}
        onChange={setOptionSelectedList}
        isMulti
        value={optionSelectedList}
      />

      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add option</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Example;
```